# Overwrite old PDF on LaTeX build (Sublime 3)

Tags: windows-10, latex, sublimetext3, miktex

this is my first time working with LaTeX. Everything runs fine so far, but I have one problem.

I am using Sublime Text 3 with the LaTeXTools plugin and MiKTeX on Windows 10. 
The first build runs successfully and creates all needed files (.aux .bbl .blg .log .pdf .synctext.gz .toc).

But when I run the build a second time, the process won't overwrite the old files, even if the build sais it was successful.

Is there anything I need to know?

Greetings

H4rd_B4se

Comment: Have you opened the pdf with acrobat reader during the build?

Comment: @r-stein No, not with Acrobat Reader, but with sumatra pdf, because it is recommended for reversal use. I don't know how, but I compiled it once with TeXStudio and now it is even working in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that LaTeXTools has some issues on it's first build. I used TeXStudio once for initial build and now it is also working in Sublime Text 3 :)